# Can I fire functions based on an appended list of <li> elements?

Tags: jquery, ajax, append, operators

For the sake of keeping the post clean, I have scaled down everything. I'm trying to add things to the dom after I remove the last `<li>` element from the page, which has been appended via jQuery.

I have an `.each` function that uses a JSON array to populate an unordered list via `.append()`.

```
var businessList = $('ul');
var businessInfo = [{"id": 10004, "category": "food"}]

$.each(businessInfo, function(idx, obj) {
        $(businessList).append('<li id="business-' + this.id + '">');
});
```

Then I have an `$.ajax` call that removes each `<li>` after checking a few things on submit. Either by using the script inside the `.done` or `beforeSend:` functions.

Everything works fine until I try to add a function to fire once the last `<li>` is removed.

Lets say I want a `<button>` to `fadeIn()` at the same time or after the last `<li>` element disappears, I've been trying things like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    data: dataSource,
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function() {
    //Invalid:
        if ($('li.class').is(':empty')) {
            xhr.abort();
        } 
    //Valid:
        else {
            $('li.class').remove();
        }

}).done(function() {
    $('document').ready(function() {
        if ($('li').length == 0) {
            $('.continue-btn').fadeIn(300);
            console.log('im the last one')
        }
    //Or this
    if ($('ul li:only-child')) {
            $('.continue-btn').fadeIn(300);
        }
    });
})
```

I simply cant get it to fire only for the last `<li>` on the page. Using the same thing inside the `beforeSend:` results in slightly different behavior. (My script fires accordingly, but on the first submit, instead of the last)

I'm suspicious that its because it has been appended, and dosen't actually exist, but then again the other functions I'm calling work. Pretty confused.

========================
EDIT:

As Rens suggested below, it came down to using the `success:` function. If anyone is interested, heres the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/aquillium/qnj15g3r/

Comment: document.ready() inside done doesn't make sense

Comment: I know, it was just to see if it would recheck and notice the missing <li> tag.

Comment: Ok, could you provide html? And what does console log tell you?

Comment: Console is clear, nothing being thrown. The only relevant HTML I could provide is the hardcoded <ul> which I tell the array to append to. I'll see if I can get a working fiddle. Thanks

Comment: Also, i always use the complete: function() callback, that is always working for me, but what you also could do is directly after removing the li to check if the length is 1 and then remove it and then fadeIn the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this and see what console gives you:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var $doc = $(document);

    $doc.on('click', '.any-element', function(){
        console.log('execute ajax call');
        $('li.class').remove();
        var ajaxurl = 'escreen.php',
        $.ajax({
            url: ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                buttons: $values,
            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log('Yay it worked');
                if($('li').length==0){
                    $('.continue-btn').fadeIn(300);
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log('Something went wrong');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok I've amended your code into my example [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aquillium/7h68jwpx/1/) which produces the same result as I'm getting locally. Button appears on first submit

Comment: Also, there's something wrong with the fiddle... It doesn't work when you first visit the page, and need to tell it to run to see what I'm seeing. console throws a 403 on first go. Not sure why.

Comment: Got it. Had a few logical issues wrong. Im still waking up, but It did come down to the `success:` option. Thanks for your help mate. Here's the final product: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aquillium/xt2s1eg2/)

Comment: Yes the succes function never lets me down either :) use it from now on :p goos you fixed it I am glad to hear that.